# is possible to convert an MBCS to DBCS?

Tags: c#

is possible to convert an MBCS to DBCS?

Answer (score 2):

```
 Encoding.Convert(Encoding, Encoding, Byte[])
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx